# Checkbox filtering using JQUERY selected cb list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am doing filter with checkbox using JQuery. I want to put diferent div selected checkbox list , also when I click  delete  the category's icon , It will be delete selected checkbox list and other div area's checkbox list. How can i do this please help ?

Like This IMAGE :   [image]

You can viev with JSDFiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/XRJ2d/**

HTML :

```
<div style="background-color:#ccc; width:90%; height:30px;">
Selected checkbox Filter list ->   



<br>
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iWr1.jpg"/>

    <br><br><br><br>

<div class="tags">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="arts" />
            Arts
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="computers" />
            Computers
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="health" />
            Health
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" />
            Video Games
        </label>
    </div>
    <ul class="results">
        <li class="arts computers">Result 1</li>
        <li class="video-games">Result 2</li>
        <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3</li>
        <li class="arts video-games">Result 4</li>
    </ul>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {


            $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
                $('.results > li').hide();
                if( $('div.tags').find('input:checked').length > 0)
                {
                $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                    $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
                });
                }else{
                    $('.results > li').show();
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: let me just check if I got it right, when you click on a checkbox, you want another div to be created showing the category of it and when you click on delete on that div those categories should be deleted, right?

Comment: do you not want the checkboxes to be displayed?

Comment: seems a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve, care to explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want, just give it a little style and volla: http://jsfiddle.net/XRJ2d/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
            $('.results > li').hide();
            $('#tags').html('<div id="selectedTags">Selected Tags : </div>');
            if( $('div.tags').find('input:checked').length > 0)
            {
            $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
                $('#tags').append('<span class="tagDiv">'+$(this).attr('rel').toUpperCase()+'<span class="delete">x</span></span>');
            });
            }else{
                $('.results > li').show();
            }
        });
    $(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
        var tagName=$(this).parent().text();
        tagName=tagName.slice(0,-1).toLowerCase();
        $('input').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('rel')==tagName){
                $(this).trigger('click');
                $(this).trigger('click');
                $(this).attr('checked',false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helping . I want like this